# bundling failed: ambiguous resolution tries to require `react-native`

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, ambiguous, react-native-twitter-signin

I am developing a react native App It was working fine until i install The npm package

> react-native-twitter-signin

. After that when i run the command

> npm run android

the following error showing

> error: bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module `D:\tmp\Taam feb
>   final\Feb4\index.js` tries to require `react-native`, but there are
>   several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:
>
> - `D:\tmp\Taam feb
>     final\Feb4\node_modules\react-native-twitter-signin\node_modules\react-native\package.json`
>
>   - `D:\tmp\Taam feb final\Feb4\node_modules\react-native\package.json`

here is my Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Hotel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native-storybook-loader": "^1.8.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "fonts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cluster": "^0.7.7",
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "firebase": "^5.7.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.5.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.22.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-module": "0.0.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.2.2",
    "react-native-twitter-signin": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you follow the all steps in https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin#setup

Comment: @Brijesh Shiroya Yes i did